# How do I find out the total number of accepted answers?

Tags: support, search, accepted-answer

Can someone please suggest a query to directly see the number of answers I posted that were accepted. Right now I have to manually count from total given answers.

Hope there is an easy way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You currently have 37 accepted answers:

https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A1562548+isaccepted%3A1

---

Note the query that is used:

```
user:1562548 isaccepted:1
```

For other users, just change the user ID number.

Comment: Grate.Its show easy to find. Thanks. :) Have a good day :)

Comment: Note that you can also use `user:me` instead of your own userid.

Comment: @GeorgeDuckett is right and if we're at notes, worth noting you can change "isaccepted" to "hasaccepted" to see questions which you asked and accepted an answer to.