# How do I find the number of questions I have answered?

Tags: support, answers, search

The closest match upon searching was [How do I find out the total number of accepted answers?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/178291/how-do-i-find-out-the-total-number-of-accepted-answers)

However my query is slightly different. I also tried searching existing queries but couldn't find what I am looking for.

I would like to know the number of questions I have answered month wise since **1st May 2013** till **28th Feb 2014**. I am not looking for **Accepted** or **Upvoted** answers. Just a summary of all the answers. For example

```
May 2013    10
June 2013   13
July 2013   14
'
'
' And so on
```

It's that time of the year when I have to submit this info to my MVP lead and I really do not want to backtrack and manually calculate the info that I need.

Any suggestion on how should I proceed?

Comment: Do you intend to do this with the Data Explorer? If so, do you know SQL/have you made an attempt at an appropriate SQL query?

Comment: @Emracool: I have seen different queries such as [THIS](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/49943/interesting-queries-on-data-explorer) And I tried editing couple of them and trying them but I guess I don't have a hang of it. So if there is already a query written then yes, that would be of great help else if there is an inbuilt feature that I am not aware of then that would save me time as well :)

Comment: Are you looking for answers written by you, or overall on the site? Also, "the number of questions answered" and "the number of answers" may be different in general.

Comment: @cheapeffectivedietpills: Answers written by me. One moment. I will update the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think You need this query

```
SET NOCOUNT ON

SELECT SUBSTRING(CONVERT(VARCHAR(11), A.CreationDate, 113), 4, 8) AS Date, Count(A.Id) AS Answers

FROM Posts AS A INNER JOIN Users AS U ON A.OwnerUserId=U.Id
WHERE A.ParentID Is Not Null AND U.Id = ##UserId##
GROUP BY SUBSTRING(CONVERT(VARCHAR(11), A.CreationDate, 113), 4, 8)
```

[**Number of Questions answered by Users In MonthWise**](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/179088/number-of-questions-answered-by-users-in-monthwise)

Output Would be

[image]

Comment: Thanks for taking time to answer my query. Let me go through it and I will get back to you in sometime. I am in a conference and may take some time to reply.

Comment: Simply Perfect! :) Thanks again for your time.

Answer (score 2):

I have created a query in Data.SE for [Month wise number of answers by User](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/179087/month-wise-number-of-answers-by-user)

```sql
SELECT DateName( month , DateAdd( month , MONTH(CreationDate) , -1 ) ) AS [Month]
     , YEAR(CreationDate) AS [Year]
     , COUNT (Id) AS Answers
  FROM Posts
 WHERE OwnerUserId = ##UserId##
   AND PostTypeId = 2
 GROUP BY MONTH(CreationDate) , YEAR(CreationDate)
 ORDER BY YEAR(CreationDate) ASC, MONTH(CreationDate) ASC
```

Result sample:

```
Month     Year Answers 
--------- ---- ------- 
May       2012 2       
June      2012 10      
July      2012 15      
August    2012 83      
September 2012 60      
October   2012 35      
November  2012 24      
December  2012 12      
January   2013 6       
February  2013 2       
March     2013 3       
April     2013 28      
May       2013 45      
June      2013 14      
July      2013 60      
August    2013 38      
September 2013 25      
October   2013 1       
January   2014 1
```

Comment: Thanks for taking time to answer my query. Let me go through it and I will get back to you in sometime. I am in a conference and may take some time to reply.

Comment: @SiddharthRout - Sure but maximum time you can take is 6 to 8 weeks. :)

Comment: I tried your query with my User ID `1140579` and it didn't give me any results. However @VigneshKumar's query gave me the results as I wanted. I am just trying to understand both the queries and doing a few random checks to verify the output

Comment: @SiddharthRout - You probably used it in *Meta* Stack Overflow. I have updated the link.

Comment: + 1 Works perfectly now :)